# Organizing Microsoft Azure DevOps Projects

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question about Microsoft DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services or VSTS). I have multiple applications that are set up as separate projects, but we have basically one team of devs. Some of the older projects are TFS based some are git.

Ideally I would like to create a board based on the team and 'attach' projects to the board. Or something that ends up being roughly the equivalent of this.

I can't seem to find anything close to this. Does anyone have any ideas? Or any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do this by using [AzureDevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1), using API's you can do anything you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to check it out.

Comment: I've provided the details as mentioned in my comment. please go through the links. BTW accept/upvote my answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment you can use the [AzureDevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

> Representational State Transfer (REST) APIs are service endpoints that
>   support sets of HTTP operations (methods), which provide create,
>   retrieve, update, or delete access to the service's resources
>
> Most REST APIs are accessible through our [client
>   libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1#client-libraries),
>   which can be used to greatly simplify your client code.

Once you created your own board, you can fill up the details using the REST API response.